# How to properly use awk in ksh?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have:

```
  1 #!/bin/ksh
  2 BEGIN { print "START" }
  3       { print "Hello World" }
  4 END   { print "STOP"   }
  5 
  6 
  7 exit 0
```

then when I try to run the file the following errors appears:

```
./file[2]: BEGIN: not found
./file[3]: syntax error: `{' unmatched
```

Does the `awk` command need to be in front of the `BEGIN` keyword?

Comment: If you're not doing any shell-related activities, why do you need to use `ksh` at all?  Why not `#!/bin/awk`?

Comment: What you have here is a frankenscript with awk and shell parts mashed together. You need `awk` to run awk scripts. `ksh` doesn't understand awk scripts and isn't smart enough to run `awk` unless you tell it to. Also you missed a `"` after `STOP` in your script.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, that'd be `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` (or `/bin/awk` depening on where `awk` is to be found)

Answer (score 4):

As I interpret your question, you're trying to get a simple `awk` script to run, and then you'll elaborate a `ksh` script around it.  Towards that end, you'll need to modify your script like this:

```
  1 #!/bin/ksh
  2 awk 'BEGIN { print "START" } \
  3       { print "Hello World" } \
  4 END   { print "STOP"  }'
  5 
  6 
  7 exit 0
```

Your script will execute `awk` (from $PATH) with a big string as the `awk` script. The big string is single-quoted to prevent `ksh` from doing string interpolation, and backslashes exist as the last character on lines 2,3,4 to make it one big string, not 3 smaller ones.

The `ksh` script will appear to hang after printing "START".  Just hit "return" or "enter" a few times. You'll see "Hello World" on every "enter". Do control-D to indicate end-of-file to `awk`. The `awk` process will print "STOP" and exit.

To do other things, you'll need to write more `ksh` - give `awk` an input file, send out put into a file or pipe, something else.

Comment: The backslashes are unecessary and should be removed. (Note that in case you want to keep the superfluous backslashes, then, strictly, you'd need to terminate the clauses by semicolons, even though awk's usually accept the code without.)